# How do I create an argument in Python?

Tags: python

> islem = str(input("İslem seciniz: "))

What will be the difference if I use an argument parser instead of input?

Comment: You will be able to pass your inputs from the command line or through a shell script (.bat or .sh or .P1) depending on the platform.

Comment: An argument parser accepts arguments to the script, e.g. `python myscript.py --foo bar baz 42`, while `input` will ask for the input sometime during program execution and read it from stdin.

Comment: Depends on your program design. Both have different use cases. If your program needs parameters only once, use argparser.

Comment: Obligatory: `input` isn't an argument. [*Yes it is!*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ohDB5gbtaEQ)

Answer (score 2):

For example:

Input - you will paste in Command Line when it has been required in script.

Argument - you will paste before running Python.

Script:

```py
import sys


argis = sys.argv[1]

inputis = input("Input something:")

print(f"This argument has been pasted in Command Line before run: {argis}")
print(f"This input has been pasted in Command Line when asked for it: {inputis}")
```

Command Line:

```
python input_vs_arg.py "BestArg"
```

`"BestArg"` is your argument

After that your code will be executed and function `input()` will ask for input:

```
Input something:
```

You will add `Best Input` for example.

```
Input something:Best Input
```

Your input is `Best Input`

At the end you will get `print`.

```
This argument has been pasted in Command Line before run: BestArg
This input has been pasted in Command Line when asked for it: Best Input
```